# Yii Expander Widget

Tags: php, jquery, yii

I am trying to use Jquery Expander extension for Yii framework, but I can't make it work.

This is the link to the extensions:

[LINK](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/jqueryexpander/)

ERROR:

```
Error 500: <h1>CException</h1>
<p>Alias "ext.expander.Expander" is invalid. Make sure it points to an existing PHP file and the file is readable. (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/yii/framework/YiiBase.php:322)</p>
```

VIEW:

```
<?php
                $this->widget('application.extensions.expander.Expander',array(
                    'content'=>$data->incidencia_descripcion,
                    'config'=>array('slicePoint'=>10, 'expandText'=>'Leer más', 'userCollapseText'=>'Ocultar', 'preserveWords'=>false)
                ));
            ?>
```

I tried also:

```
$this->widget('ext.expander.Expander',array(
                        'content'=>$data->incidencia_descripcion,
                        'config'=>array('slicePoint'=>10, 'expandText'=>'Leer más', 'userCollapseText'=>'Ocultar', 'preserveWords'=>false)
                    ));
                ?>
```

However this works:

```
$this->widget('ext.google.XGoogleChart',array(
    'type'=>'pie',
    'title'=>'Browser market 2008',
    'data'=>array('IE7'=>22,'IE6'=>30.7,'IE5'=>1.7,'Firefox'=>36.5,'Mozilla'=>1.1,'Safari'=>2,'Opera'=>1.4),
    'size'=>array(400,300), // width and height of the chart image
    'color'=>array('6f8a09', '3285ce','dddddd'), // if there are fewer color than slices, then colors are interpolated.
));
```

Answer (score 0):

when i want to use ckeditor widget for my project i following this way.you can try this way maybe receive your question.
1)download ckeditor from here http://ckeditor.com/download
2)create folder of ckeditor in main folder of yii and place all content of ckeditor in it.
3)download extension from here http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/ckeditor/
and extract it in extensions folder
you would have content in extensions\ckeditor\
4)`<?php $this->widget('application.extensions.ckeditor.CKEditorWidget',array(
                                  "model"=>$model,                 # Data-Model
                                  "attribute"=>'experience',          # Attribute in the Data-Model
                                  #"defaultValue"=>$model->experience,     # Optional
                                  "config" => array(
                                      "height"=>"200px",
                                      "width"=>"400px",
                                      "toolbar"=>"Basic",
                                      ),
                                  ) ); ?>`
 you can try this way for expander widget

Comment: I have that way, my extension is on: mywebapp/protected/extensions/expander/Expander.php